# Extract text using regular expression between keywords

Tags: regex, scala

I have only recently started working on regular expressions and only know the basics, none of the advanced or later learning stuff... like backreferences, Lookarounds etc.

I have this small problem that I need to solve but am unable to write a regex for it. The pattern looks simple, but I don't know how to write it.

The string:

```
[CS]v1|<bunch of alpha numberic text>[CE]
```

So [CS] and [CE] mark the start and end of a string.. Now I need to extract only the `<bunch of alpha numeric text>` from with the tags.. 
The RE should even leave out the `"v1|"` part of it.

Any help please? I have been over the forum multiple times and I see posts of extracting texts from between etc, but am unable to apply the same to my problem.. :/

Thanks for all / any help.

P.S - Am doing this in scala as I need to work with Spark.

Update: I tried this.. not the best, but its getting me results for now. This is based on the assumption that the field in interest will always obey the above pattern.

```
val pattern = "\\w+-\\w+\\b".r
val f = (pattern findAllIn visitor_id).mkString("")
val result = f.replace("-", "")
```

So for a string like

```
[CS]v1|2C33FAB2851D11F4-6000017080003FAF[CE]
```

the above code will give me `"2C33FAB2851D11F46000017080003FAF"`..

But What I would really like to learn is if there is way to identify the boundaries [CS] and [CE] and get text in between that.

Comment: can you use groups ?

Comment: guess not yet got to that topic of RE. :( .. but I did update my question with what I have tried... If that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described your requirements very well. It looks like a simple substring formula is all you need.

```
val str = "[CS]v1|<bunch of alpha numberic text>[CE]"
val extract = str.substring(7, str.length-4)
```

But if you really want to use regex this might do.

```
val str = "[CS]v1|<bunch of alpha numberic text>[CE]"
val extractor = "[^|]+\\|(.*)\\[..]".r
val extract = str match {
  case extractor(s) => s
  case _ => ""
}
```

Comment: That looks like something I need to put on a regex parser and see what it does.. but it does get me the results.. thanks for that.

Comment: `[^|]+` = everything that isn't `|`; `\\|` = then the `|`; `(.*)` = capture group; `\\[..]` = end with 2 characters inside brackets